# NSArray index 1 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
-(IBAction)someMethod:(UIStepper *)sender{
    int x=sender.value; //This is an integer from 0-8;
    NSLog(@"%f",sender.value);
    NSArray *rpmValues = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i", nil];
    if (x<=[rpmValues count]) {

        myLabel.text = [rpmValues objectAtIndex:x];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i",[rpmValues count]);
}
```

Above is my code, what I want to do is to change UILabel display by changing UIStepper. This is very straight forward. But when I change press the stepper value, it crashes:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -   [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
```

And the [rpmValue count] is 9. I really got confused. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Other than the `if` statement needing to use `<` and not `<=`, this code looks OK. Are you 100% sure the error is coming from this code and not some other place?

Comment: Setting `int x` manually to 1 seems to work for me, can you try this? Your NSLog statement is wrong, what does `NSLog(@"%d",sender.value);` print? Something else must be causing the problem.

Comment: The problem is when x = [rpmValues count]. Getting an object at that index does not work as index starts from 0.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get this error message from the code you posted -- I tried it out and it worked fine up until the last item which can be fixed like the comments have said. So, I believe your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Also, your error is pointing to a mutable array, and rpmValues is immutable. You should add an exception breakpoint to your project, so the line where the error occurs will be highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code seems fine (see my comment on the question); your problem could arise from the use of

```
if (x<=[rpmValues count]) {
```

This will include the count of the array, which exceeds the index range by one. Use

```
if (x < [rpmValues count]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least `if (x<=[rpmValues count])` should be `if (x<[rpmValues count])`. Otherwise if you have an array with, say, two entities then you're allowing yourself to access indices 0, 1 and 2 — three possibilities in total.

Is it possible you've set a `maximumValue` on your stepper of '9' based on similar logic?